# Map.mapTo to another map

Tags: kotlin

I want to map `Map<DAO, Int>` to `Map<String, Boolean>` but I can't return Map.Entry in map function:

```
itemsWithQuantity.mapTo(mutableMapOf<String, Boolean>(), { it.key.toString() to it.value != 0 })
```

(of course I am using more complex mapping function, but it doesn't matter, problem is same)

It says

```
MutableMap<String, Boolean> is not a subtype of MutableCollection<Pair<String, Boolean>>.
```

So how can I return Map.Entry instead of Pair?

Now I am doing it this way:

```
val detailsIds = mutableMapOf<String, Boolean>()
itemsWithQuantity.forEach { item, quantity -> detailsIds.put(it.key.toString(), it.value != 0) }
```

But I want to use mapTo

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`associateTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-to.html) instead:

```
xs.associateTo(mutableMapOf<String, Boolean>(), { "${it.key}" to (it.value != 0) })
```

<sup>Also, note the brackets around `it.value != 0`.</sup>

The [`mapTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-to.html) function, similarly to [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html), doesn't collect the results into a `Map`, but instead works with a `Collection`, expecting you to provide a `MutableCollection<Pair<String, Boolean>>`.

Comment: associateTo only works with collections (your xs). That does not work if xs is a Map, as it is asked.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment, the accepted answer works for transforming a `Collection` into a `Map`, but not for transforming a map into another map. For that, I had to use something like below:

```kotlin
itemsWithQuantity.map { it.key.toString() to (it.value != 0) }.toMap()
```